# Python Sklearn validation.py:386 error while using predict SVC model

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

While using:

```
grid_search.GridSearchCV(svm.SVC(), parameters).fit(x_train, y_train).predict(x)
```

I get the following error:

> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
>     DeprecationWarning)

How can i solve it?

Thanks

Comment: A `DeprecationWarning` is not an error. It just tells you that some features won't be available anymore in the versions to come

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your dataframe look like? It is probably due to the shape of x_train/x_test.

Comment: my code is based on [link](http://www.ippatsuman.com/2014/08/13/day-and-night-an-image-classifier-with-scikit-learn/). I have used the food101 examples of apple-pies and pizzas and was testing the image on [link](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qSRTbJKDMk4/maxresdefault.jpg)

Comment: Can you add a few lines of data to the example? This will make answering the question probably much easier.

Comment: The dataset used is available at [food101](https://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/datasets_extra/food-101/) and the image used for test is [here](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qSRTbJKDMk4/maxresdefault.jpg)